# Using DB2 driver with Informix

Tags: sql, go, db2, informix

I'm new to IBM platforms and will soon be working with an Informix-based system.  My preferred language (Go) has third-party driver for DB2.

Haven't tried yet, but does anyone know if I can use this driver for Informix too (or can suggest a driver)?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt it.  Informix and DB2 are very different databases, even though both are owned by the same company (which also owns Netezza).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of...

Comment: Informix supports the DRDA protocols, but your Informix DBA must set up the proper "listener" on the informix instance.

Answer (score 1):

IBM offers integrated driver packages like "IBM Data Server Driver Package" that work both with DB2 (on Linux, Unix, and Windows and on z/OS and IBM i) and with Informix. So for your problem of using a third-party driver for the language Go it is very likely that it will work with Informix, too. The [driver for Python and Django](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb) is for DB2 and Informix - other language, same solutions.

Here is the link to an [article describing parts of the driver architecture](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1012dsclidriver/index.html). At the end of that page are links to download the mentioned IBM Data Server Driver Packages.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it on community versions first of DB2 and Informix... Will post results.

Comment: Quick update, per hunch, I was able to use ODBC library to connect.  Works perfectly!